# Почему выводит ошибку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Пишу программу на python с СУБД SQLite. Столкнулся с небольшой проблемкой. Надо заменить значение в строке таблицы, если дата в столбце DATE(записана в текстовом формате ГГГГ-ММ-ДД) меньше даты на ПК.
Реализовал все с помощью кода:

```
x = datetime.date.today()
conn = sqlite3.connect(база данных)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("UPDATE LC SET STAT = 'Просрочена' WHERE DC < (?)",x)
```

Но к сожалению выводит ошибку: ValueError: parametrs are of unsupported type.

Подскажите как решить проблему

Comment: `x = datetime.date.today()`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, в коде так и написанно. Я просто с телефона писал и допустил ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для форматирования даты есть метод [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

```
import datetime

x = datetime.date.today()
print(x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))  # 2020-01-20
```

Также конкретно для формата `YYYY-MM-DD` есть метод [`isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat):

```
import datetime

x = datetime.date.today()
print(x.isoformat())  # 2020-01-20
```

Как вариант еще можно просто приводить к строке через `str`, но я бы советовал вместо этого явно указывать нужный формат (предыдущие два варианта). Но и такой способ тоже рабочий:

```
import datetime

x = datetime.date.today()
print(str(x))  # 2020-01-20
```

Соответственно, для вашего случая:

```
x = datetime.date.today()
conn = sqlite3.connect(база данных)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("UPDATE LC SET STAT = 'Просрочена' WHERE DC < (?)", (x.isoformat(),))
```

Comment: Ок, попробую, но вроде при использовании datetime.date.today() дата сразу в таком формате

Comment: @DGDays, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Я использовал datetime.date.today() для занесения даты в БД и все записывается в таком же формате. Но я чуть позже попробую и отпишусь)

Comment: Дата не "сразу в таком формате", а только после приведений к строке, например с помощью `str` или при выводе через `print`.

Comment: выводит новую ошибку: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 10 supplied.

Comment: @DGDays, в execute вторым параметром должен передаваться tuple, поправил ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо)))